# How to center a image

Tags: html, css

I have a website in which there is a circle image.

I want that image to be in center at all time.(small/medium/large screens)

To clear it [visit](http://namarsaham.website.tk/).

The code goes here:-

```
<html>
<head>
<title>
Maintenance in Progress
</title>
<style>
.timer {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 60px;
  color: white;
   position: absolute;
    right: 500px;
    bottom: 0;
}
body {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}
.utxt{
    position: absolute;
}

.circle{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
}
.dtxt{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
</style>
</head>
<body background="maintenance/bg.png">
<img class="utxt" src="maintenance/utxt.png"></img>
<img class="circle" src="maintenance/circle.png"></img>
<img class="dtxt" src="maintenance/dtxt.png"></img>
<div class="timer" id="demo"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Please help me out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `transform: translate(-50%, -50%);` to your existing styles for `.circle`.

```
.circle{
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Full code goes here, with the update.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>
Maintenance in Progress
</title>
<style>
.timer {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 60px;
  color: white;
   position: absolute;
    right: 500px;
    bottom: 0;
}
body {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}
.utxt{
    position: absolute;
}

.circle{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.dtxt{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
</style>
</head>
<body background="maintenance/bg.png">
<img class="utxt" src="maintenance/utxt.png"></img>
<img class="circle" src="maintenance/circle.png"></img>
<img class="dtxt" src="maintenance/dtxt.png"></img>
<div class="timer" id="demo"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Glad to help you out.

Answer (score 0):

To your circle image add the rule:

```
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
```

Answer (score 0):

Add  `transform: translate(-50%, -50%);` to your existing styles for `.circle`.

That makes your image vertically and horizontally centered.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe adding this to your css can help, if i got it right:

```
-webkit-align-items: center;
align-items: center;
-webkit-justify-content: center;
justify-content: center;
```